# Default data type of Java Interpreter for Floating contants

Tags: java, floating-point, interpreter

This might be the simple question to all but it messes with my head with a question,"Why it is so?"

As you can see in the below code, I have declared a `float` variable and assigned a value to it. When this piece of code get's compiled and interpreted, I will get an error as `possible loss of precision` which is right as default data type of java interpreter for floating constant is double.

**Query 1 :** I wonder, why should I waste memory in my application for double when my floating constant can accommodate in number of bytes float provide.

**Query 2:** Now if I specify `float a = 3.1415f ;` I will get the output but now how much memory is allocated for my `a` variable.

```
float a = 3.1415 ;
System.out.println("Value of a:"+a);
```

I really want to understand this hack, why is it so?

Comment: check Patricia Shanahan's answer! the heart of the error lies in "my floating constant can accommodate in number of bytes float provide" your constant cannot be accomodated into neither a float nor a double! that's why loss of precision occurs and you must the 'f' so the compiler approximates it as best he can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Query 1 : I wonder, why should I waste memory in my application for double when my floating constant can accommodate in number of bytes float provide.

It's simply a matter of floating point literals defaulting to `double`. From [section 3.10.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d (§4.2.3).

You need to decide which type you want, and write the appropriate literal. You almost certainly shouldn't base your choice of data type on how many digits you specify - and be aware that just because `float` can maintain up to a certain number of decimal digits of accuracy doesn't mean that it can *exactly* represent numbers with that many significant digits. No binary floating point type can exactly represent 0.1 for example, in the same way that you can't write "one third" as a finite decimal number.

As a side note, personally I like to add the `d` explicitly for `double` anyway, just for clarity.

Next:

> Query 2: Now if I specify float a = 3.1415f ; I will get the output but now how much memory is allocated for my a variable.

4 bytes, because it's a `float`.

Comment: this answer fails to illustrate the huge mistake the user is making when he says "when my floating constant can accommodate in number of bytes float provide". Clearly the root of his problem is the false belief that decimal 3.1415 can be accurately represented in a float or double. I'm tempted to downvote it. Computers work in binary underneath, damn the law of leaky abstractions: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: @Daren: Edited. (Although float/double aren't the only floating point representations, of course. 3.1415 is represented in a floating *decimal* point type.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not doubting your impressive knowledge, I wish I had a fraction of your expertise... :) I just thought the enquirer had left with the outer layer of reasoning corrected but failed to see his true mistake. A curious mind he has to inquire why on such triviality, but probably left without knowing truly why... it was more than just a compiler convention.

Answer (score 1):

"Query 1 : I wonder, why should I waste memory in my application for double when my floating constant can accommodate in number of bytes float provide."

This incorporates a false assumption. Neither float nor double can really store your value:

```
float: 3.141499996185302734375
double: 3.141500000000000181188397618825547397136688232421875
```

Both are approximations, but the double is a much closer approximation than the float.

If you are not going to think about the required precision for a literal, it is safer to use double, so that it the appropriate default. If you have analyzed the effect of float rounding error, and have decided float is acceptable, you can and should make it a float literal.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1: Because floating point calculations are almost always involve approximation. `double` types has a larger precision (double-precision) that float, so it has a reduced chance of losing any data due to approximation. I think this may be a reason for considering any floating point literals as doubles.

Query 2: For both of the cases your `a` variable will be 32-bit in size (check out [the float section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) here). In the -

```
float a = 3.1414;
```

statement, the value is being cast into a float, which is known as a narrowing conversion. Java doesn't allow that, but it allows the opposite - widening conversion.

Answer (score 0):

As defined in the spec, a float is a 32-bit IEEE 754 value, so it consumes 4 bytes. This document explains the defaults and the reasoning: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html. Sun/Oracle's advice is that if the precision of a double is not needed, and memory is an issue, use a float as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

let me answer with a question:

why does this small fragment of code print **false** and not **true**?

```
float a = 3.1415;
double b = 3.1415;
double c = a;
System.out.println((b==c));
```

... got it? exactly!

However it is true that this is not the whole logic, since 0.1f and 0.1 are different numbers in binary representation, but 0.5f and 0.5 are the same, the compiler should allow you to declare float f = 0.5; but it does not evaluate if each number "fits" in afloat or requires a double without precision loss... it just assumes precision will be lost for the vast majority, and is rightly so.